# Using advanced ccs icons in email signatures

Tags: html, css, email

Having the age old issues of how to attach graphics in email signature. I.E. I can attach the images as links, which means outlook users will not see it. I can embed them as encoded images, but that only works if sending from outlook (we use both gmail and outlook) and so forth. So I had a thought, what if I just use CSS icons, that could save me a bit of headache.

Here is my problem though, how would I go about that. On a wepage it is simple as, just add it in a stylesheet or between style tags as below

```
<style>
.marker{
margin-top: 1.0em;
margin-left: 1.0em;
position: relative;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 0.5em;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3em;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.3em;
font-size: 12px;

}

.marker:after{
 position: absolute;
content: "";
top: 0.3em;
left: 0em;
width: 0em;
height: 0em;
border-top: 0.9em solid rgba(44, 44, 44, 0);
border-bottom: 0.9em solid transparent;
border-left: 1.4em solid #2C2C2C;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);  
}

.marker:before{
 border: 0.5em solid #2C2C2C;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.8em;
    left: -1.28em;
    display: block;
    width: 1.1em;
    height: 1.1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

However, I don't seem to be able to get that solution to work in e-mail signature. Thought maybe I could actually embed it in the div style argument, but not certain if I can put advance styles in a div style.

What I am talking about is something along the lines of the below

```
<div style=".marker{
margin-top: 1.0em;
margin-left: 1.0em;
position: relative;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 0.5em;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3em;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.3em;
font-size: 12px;

}

.marker:after{
 position: absolute;
content: "";
top: 0.3em;
left: 0em;
width: 0em;
height: 0em;
border-top: 0.9em solid rgba(44, 44, 44, 0);
border-bottom: 0.9em solid transparent;
border-left: 1.4em solid #2C2C2C;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);  
}

.marker:before{
 border: 0.5em solid #2C2C2C;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.8em;
    left: -1.28em;
    display: block;
    width: 1.1em;
    height: 1.1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
}"></style>
```

Comment: `<div style=".marker{...}"></style>` I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do here but it certainly isn't valid CSS or HTML

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could have tried. But no, that won't work. The style you add in the `style` attribute should be just the styling for that element, no complete stylesheet for the document or even just subelements.

But it's true that most mail clients will ignore `style` tags. Also they may ignore or explicitly remove some inline styles, so I'd make sure to test it thoroughly on a wide variety of clients, or maybe decide against it right away and just use a couple of images or a single sprite image.

Comment: I may not have been that clear about my underlying issue. I wanted to see if there was some way of avoiding embedding images as I am in a position where gmail will not embed images (only urls to images) and outlook will not look up images by default. Outlook wants them embedded instead.

Comment: I think both Gmail and Outlook can show embedded images if you embedded them correctly. That aside, I understood your problem, but the answer just is "no, you cannot paste the entire stylesheet in a style attribute of a div". So you can try to style each element separately by giving them all their own style attribute. It's a lot of work, but that's all you can do.

Comment: Did you add the style element to the head in the HTML of your email? Can you try adding a [scoped style element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp) (that is, a style element with the attribute `scope` set) inside the div?